# Meu bot no Telegram está fazendo loop nas mensagens

Tags: php, telegram

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
function readUpdate($updateId) {
    $fh = fopen(basename(__FILE__, '.php').'.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fh, $updateId.' ');
    fclose($fh);
}
function sendMessage($chatId, $text) {
    if(!empty($chatId) && !empty($text)) {
        file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage?text='.$text.'&chat_id='.$chatId);
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i = 1; $i++) {
    $getUpdates = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates'), true);
    $count = count($getUpdates['result']) - 1;
    readUpdate($getUpdates['result'][$count]['message']['message_id']);
    if(strpos(file_get_contents(basename(__FILE__, '.php').'.txt'), $getUpdates['result'][$count]['message']['message_id']) !== true) {
        foreach($getUpdates['result'] as $result) {
            $updateId = $result['update_id'];
            $messageId = $result['message']['message_id'];
            $userId = $result['message']['from']['id'];
            $firstName = $result['message']['from']['first_name'];
            $lastName = $result['message']['from']['last_name'];
            $userName = $result['message']['from']['username'];
            $chatId = $result['message']['chat']['id'];
            $type = $result['message']['chat']['type'];
            $text = $result['message']['text'];
            if($text == '/start') {
                sendMessage($chatId, 'Olá '.$firstName);
                echo '[START] Mensagem de boas vindas enviada.<br>';
                continue;
            }
        }
    } else {

    }
    $i--;
}
?>
```

O retorno do `/getUpdates` é:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":444612040,
"message":{"message_id":1,"from":{"id":330782177,"first_name":"Brayan","last_name":"Noxious","username":"STRILEXLIVE"},"chat":{"id":330782177,"first_name":"Brayan","last_name":"Noxious","username":"STRILEXLIVE","type":"private"},"date":1492270909,"text":"/start","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":6}]}},{"update_id":444612041,
"message":{"message_id":2,"from":{"id":330782177,"first_name":"Brayan","last_name":"Noxious","username":"STRILEXLIVE"},"chat":{"id":330782177,"first_name":"Brayan","last_name":"Noxious","username":"STRILEXLIVE","type":"private"},"date":1492270972,"text":"Ol\u00e1"}}]}
```

As funções estão funcionando perfeitamente, tudo está okay, porem, quando eu acesso a URL do script, o script começa a enviar as mensagens para as pessoas que enviaram mensagens para o bot, e depois de ele enviar as mensagens para as pessoas que enviaram as mensagens para ele, ele começa a enviar mais uma mensagem, e assim vai, então vai spamando o chat.

A função `readUpdate` serve para o script pegar um ID único da mensagem e salvar em um arquivo .txt para o bot marcar como "mensagem lida", para não spamar, mas mesmo assim ele spama o chat.

Procurei de tudo na internet, de como ler linha por linha do arquivo .txt e ver se tal string tá na linha, etc, para tentar resolver este erro, mas não obtive sucesso.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o `offset` do Telegram para apenas obter novas mensagens, ignorando mensagens já lidas, veja em https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates.

> Identifier of the first update to be returned. Must be greater by one than the highest among the identifiers of previously received updates. By default, updates starting with the earliest unconfirmed update are returned. An update is considered confirmed as soon as getUpdates is called with an offset higher than its update_id. The negative offset can be specified to retrieve updates starting from -offset update from the end of the updates queue. All previous updates will forgotten.

---

Dessa forma se você obtêm:

```
{  
   "ok":true,
   "result":[  
      {  
         "update_id":444612040,
         "message":"..."
      },
      {  
         "update_id":444612041,
         "message":"..."
      }
   ]
}
```

Na próxima requisição para `/getUpdates` você deve informar `offset=444612042`.

Você pode utilizar várias maneiras para obter o maior `update_id` e somar um, por exemplo:

- `max(array_column($result, 'update_id')) + 1`
- `$result[count($result) - 1]['update_id'] + 1`

Para isso utilizei isto:

```
function saveUpdateOffset(array $result){

   file_put_contents(LOCAL_HISTORY, (max(array_column($result, 'update_id')) + 1));

}

function getUpdateOffset(){

    if(file_exists(LOCAL_HISTORY) && is_readable(LOCAL_HISTORY)) {
        return (int)file_get_contents(LOCAL_HISTORY);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Assim chamando por `getUpdateOffset` irá obter o último `id`, se existir. E quando chamar por `saveUpdateOffset`, informando os dados da requisição atual, irá atualizar o arquivo para o `id` mais recente, que será obtido na próxima chamada.

---

### Exemplo:

Você pode tanto armazenar o `offset`e utiliza-lo na próxima chamada ou uma outra opção é simplesmente fazer uma nova requisição para `/getUpdates` para que ele ignore o que já foi lido (e portanto processado e enviado uma resposta).

Enfim, poderá utilizar isto:

```
const TELEGRAM_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx';
const TELEGRAM_URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.TELEGRAM_TOKEN;
const LOCAL_HISTORY = 'historico.txt';
```

```
function getUpdates($offset = 0){

   $jsonNotificacoes = sendRequest(TELEGRAM_URL.'/getUpdates?offset='.$offset);

    if($jsonNotificacoes == false){
        return false;
    }

    return json_decode($jsonNotificacoes, true)['result'];

}

function getMessages($getUpdates_result){

    return array_column($getUpdates_result, 'message');

}

function saveUpdateOffset($getUpdates_result){

   file_put_contents(LOCAL_HISTORY, (max(array_column($getUpdates_result, 'update_id')) + 1));

}

function getUpdateOffset(){

    if(file_exists(LOCAL_HISTORY) && is_readable(LOCAL_HISTORY)) {
        return (int)file_get_contents(LOCAL_HISTORY);
    }

    return 0;

}

function sendMessage($chatId, $text){

    if(empty($chatId) && empty($text)) {
       return false;
    }

    return sendRequest(TELEGRAM_URL.'/sendMessage?text='.$text.'&chat_id='.$chatId);

}

function sendRequest($url){

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
        CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 2,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
        CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT => 500,
        CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME => 1,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1
    ]);

    return curl_exec($ch);

}
```

```
$updates = getUpdates( getUpdateOffset() );

if($updates) {

    saveUpdateOffset($updates);

    $mensagens = getMessages($updates);

    foreach ($mensagens as $mensagem) {

        $id     = $mensagem['chat']['id'];
        $nome   = $mensagem['from']['first_name'];
        $texto  = $mensagem['text'];

        if($texto === '/start'){

            if(sendMessage($id, 'Olá, ' . $nome)) {
                echo 'Mensagem enviada';
            }
        }

    }

}
```

---

Mudanças:

Uso de cURL, restrito para HTTPS (`CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS`), sem seguir redirecionamento (`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`) e verificando a autenticidade do SSL (`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`), com timeout de conexão de 2 segundos (`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`) e um timeout de 5 segundos para obter todo o resultado (`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`) e em caso de conexões lentas o timeout é de 1 segundo (`CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME`) e em caso de um HTTPCode diferente de 200~300 irá retornar `false` (`CURLOPT_FAILONERROR`).

O `getUpdates(int $offset)` faz a requisição para obter todas as informações do `TELEGRAM_URL/getUpdates`.

O `getMessages(array $getUpdates_result)` espera o resultado do `getUpdates`, onde irá retornar apenas os dados das mensagens.

O `saveUpdateOffset` e  `getUpdateOffset` foi descrito acima, onde apenas salva e obtêm o Offset de um arquivo `historico.txt`, a primeira função espera o resultado o `getUpdates` como primeiro parâmetro.

O `sendMessage()` ficou basicamente inalterado.

Comment: Testei localmente e não retornou nada nem enviou mensagem.

Comment: Utilize o CURL inseguro se não configurou corretamente, modificando o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` para `0` e o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` para `0`. Ajuste (ou remova) o `CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT` se sua conexão (ou do servidor alvo) for lenta.